# BBP-like formula for $\arctan5$

Tags: number-theory

### Question

I'm collecting some [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) as algorithm tests.

But I did not find the formula related to $\arctan5$. Does this formula exist?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\arctan{1}&=\frac{1}{4}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{16^n}\left(\frac{4}{8n+1}-\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+6}\right)\\
\arctan{2}&=\frac{1}{4}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{16^n}\left(\frac{4}{8n+2}+\frac{4}{8n+3}+\frac{4}{8n+4}+\frac{1}{8n+6}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)\\
\arctan{3}&=\frac{1}{4}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{16^n}\left(\frac{4}{8n+1}+\frac{4}{8n+2}-\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{2}{8n+6}\right)\\
\arctan{4}&=\frac{1}{32}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{16^{2n}}\left(\frac{64}{16n+1}-\frac{64}{16n+4}-\frac{16}{16n+5}-\frac{16}{16n+6}+\frac{4}{16n+9}-\frac{1}{16n+13}-\frac{1}{16n+14}\right)\\
\arctan{5}&=\,?\\
\arctan{6}&=\frac{1}{32}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\left(\frac{27}{64}\right)^n\left(\frac{48}{6n+1}-\frac{27}{6n+5}\right)\\
\arctan{7}&=\frac{1}{4}∑_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{16^n}\left(\frac{4}{8n+1}+\frac{4}{8n+3}+\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}+\frac{1}{8n+6}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

### Related

1. I searched $5k+i$ until $±2^{31}$ but did not find a valid coefficient.
2. According to the formula given by wiki, there is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\arctan{5}=\frac{π}{2}-\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}5^{-4n-3}\left(\frac{25}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n+3}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

But $π$ does not have a formula for $5^{-4n}$

Comment: You may still replace $\pi$ by a BBP formula and get $\arctan 5$ as a BBP formula. Even if it's not as simple as you would like, it should be expected. See https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/bbp-formulas.pdf

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut To use the formula for $\arctan 5$ given in the question statement, wouldn't doing replacing $\pi$ require a BBP formula for $\pi$ with base $5^s$ for some $s$?